# Coefficient of Determination in Neural Networks

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

Is the Coefficient of Determination a good metric to use in Neural Networks for certain situations?  I have a network where the Y value ranges from 0 to 1 so I use sigmoid.  My loss metric is MAE and I am satisfied with results.  I find that some people who I present to do not have a good understanding of certain loss metrics but recall Coefficient of Determination from previous studies.

I have not seen this metric used in Neural Networks and wonder if it is applicable or I should not use it.

To clarify good - is it a viable measure or are their issues with using it in a NN setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### In short, it's a different way of looking at a common metric.

Coefficient of Determintation is related to the common metric **Mean Squared Error** (I believe you are using it).

The two are related by:

> CoD = 1 - MSE / (variance of inputs)
>
> MSE = (variance of input) * (1 - CoD)

[See this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32596/what-is-the-difference-between-coefficient-of-determination-and-mean-squared)

Since the variance of the inputs *doesn't change as the network trains*, the Coefficient of Determination will be linearly related to the Mean Squared Error. What this means is that using CoD instead of MSE likely won't change how the network trains.

Which to choose as your metric is largely situation-dependent, since they represent ***different things***. However, if all you want is a number that changes over time to represent how well your network is trained, they both will work. One thing to note is that MSE is a minimizing function - that is, it approaches **0** as your network improves - whereas COD is a maximizing function that approaches **1** as your network improves. If you use back-propagation you will need to take that into account when calculating your gradient.

#### So in conclusion...

I don't see any overwhelming reasons *not* to use CoD, but at the same time, I don't see any reasons to *use* it either. I don't think either one has an advantage besides their interpretation, since they are mathematically quite similar.